# How to make a spinner like html style in Android?

Tags: android, spinner

I have a spinner control, I wish it can be used like a html "select" control.
For example, image a country select control (in html), populated with a countries code array and countries name array.
I wish this behavior because, countries code will not change, but countries name could does. If I want to display this name in english, spanish, french, etc, but countries codes never change.
So my question is How can I make this with an spinner in Android?
Or if you think that this is not "correct", Can you suggest me some solution?

Thank you very much.

Comment: cant understand how can be two arrays in single array>pls elaborate

Comment: no, i never said "two arrays in single array".
only think about html select control, I want the same but with a android spinner.